# Blazor azure AD retrieve email from graph API

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, active-directory, blazor-server-side

- I have implemented azure ad authentication successfully. I am able to
  login, and display the user's name.
- I now need to call the graph api to access the user's email address.
  I have my token type set to "ID" tokens in the azure portal.

Index.Razor

```
    Code {
        
            private HttpClient _httpClient;
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string userDisplayName = "";
           
        
        //this is what I am using to get the user's name
            protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
            {
                
                var authstate = await Authentication_.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
                var user = authstate.User.Identity.Name;
                if (user != null)
                {
                      Name = user;

                    // 1) this is what I'm trying to use right now. 
//The Graph API SDK 
 var attempt= await GraphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

                }
                else
                {
                    Name = "";
                }
        
        
        
                /*
        // 2)this is what I've tried to use to access the graph api
                _httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        
        
                // get a token
        
                var token = await TokenAcquisitionService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "User.Read" });
        
                // make API call
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                var dataRequest = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me");
        
                if (dataRequest.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var userData = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(await dataRequest.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
                    userDisplayName = userData.RootElement.GetProperty("displayName").GetString();
                }
        
         
                    
        
            }
```

Startup.cs

```
var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                   .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                       .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                       .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });

        

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddAuthorization();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
```

Appsettings.json

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/.auth/login/aad/callback",

    "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

  },


  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
```

When I attempt a request via the 1st tried method mentioned in the Index.razor file above (I commented it out with the number 1) I get an error of: "MSAL.Net No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call"

More details:

[This an image of my delegated permissions set in azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXJKa.png)

Lastly: this is a link the example I followed. https://github.com/wmgdev/BlazorGraphApi

Comment: Are you sure the email isn't already in the claims of the authentication state?

Comment: Just checked out the claims list and saw the email listed. Is there a specific way I can access it or should I just grab the element from the list?

Comment: You can do `authstate.User.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "email"), however, I just checked and mine has "name" and "upn" not "email" even though their values are formated as email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the optional "email" claim if you have control over the Azure AD App Registration:

[image]

After doing that, you will have an "emailaddress" claim in `authstate.User.Claims`

I just tried it in my Blazor app and it works great. I think it is possible for there to not be an email property though, so make sure you null check, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@context.User.Claims` to get a login name, in case of, login name is same as an email address, as usual.

```
< AuthorizeView>
    < Authorized>

Hello, @context.User.Claims.First( cl => cl.Type.ToString()=="preferred_username").Value

    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</ AuthorizeView>
```

Retrieving a user's login name in Blazor WASM component

[image]